# For which $u$ does the derivative $f'(u,0)$ of $f(x,y)=x^2y^2/(x^2y^2+(y-x)^2)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting**

**$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(y-x)^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$**
**(a) For which vectors $u\ne 0$ does $f'(0; u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it
exists.**

**(b) Do $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist at $0$?**

**(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?**

**(d) Is $f$ continuous at $0$?**

I have thought a lot about this problem:

For (a), let $u\neq 0$ and $u=(h,k)$ then $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+t(h,k))-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{th^2k^2}{t^2h^2k^2+t(k-h)^2}$ but I do not know what conditions $h$ and $k$ have to satisfy so that this limit exists, could someone help me please?

For (b), since $f(t,0)=0$ and $f(0,t)=0$ it is concluded that $D_1f(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0)}{t}=0$ and $D_2f(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0,t)-f(0)}{t}=0$ thus these limits exist.

For (c), we see that taking the director vector $u=(1,1)$ and doing $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}$ we see that the limit does not exist and thus the function is not differentiable in $0$

For (d), I am having trouble solving this, I am trying to calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0, y=mx}f(x,y)$and I get to that $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0, y=mx}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to 0, y=mx}\frac{x^2(mx)^2}{x^2(mx)^2+(mx-x)^2}$,I do not know if $f$ is continuous in $0$, could someone help me please?

Comment: limit does not exists, so it is not continuous and hence not differentiable but partials are both zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the limit does not exist approach $(0,0)$ along $y=0$ and along $y=x$ you get two differnt limits $0$ and $1$. This implies it is not continuous and hence not differentiable at $(0,0)$. For the directional derivative you didn't put the vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$ into the equation. You have to compute $$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+t(u_1,u_2))-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tu_1,tu_2)-f(0,0)}{t}$$$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{u_1^2u_2^2t^4}{t^5u_1^2u_2^2+t^3(u_1-u_2)^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{u_1^2u_2^2t}{t^2u_1^2u_2^2+(u_1-u_2)^2}=0,$$
for any unit vector $(u_1, u_2)$ with $u_1\neq u_2$ .

Comment: Why "you didn't put the vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$ into the equation"? Why $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+tu)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(u_1,u_2)-f(0,0)}{t}$? It should not be $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tu_1, tu_2)-f(0,0)}{t}$? And I am following the notation of the book "Analysis on manifold" by Munkres.

Comment: yes you are right it would be $f(tu_1,tu_2)$ sorry for this, corrected it is ok now. I hope it helped you.

Comment: In the third equality should not be $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{u_1^2u_2^2t^4}{t^4u_1^2u_2^2+t^2(u_2-u_1)}\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: opps you are right for this too:) this changes something seriously this means that whatever $u$ is $D_uf$ does not exist. I fix it

Comment: I think there are still errors in the end, why is $\frac{u_1^2u_2^2}{u_1^2u_2^2+(u_1-u_2)^2}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}$? It should not be $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{th^2k^2}{t^2h^2k^2+t(k-h)^2}$?

Comment: so lets correct it

Comment: actually these comptutational mistakes are mostly due to writing the solution directly in the screen.